# "Attribute Error" using pytrends library on python

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm trying to run a script using pytrends library to scrape Google Trends.

```
import pytrends
kw_list = ["covid"]
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='2021-02-01 2021-07-09', geo='BR', gprop='')
gt_o3_ytd1 = pytrends.interest_over_time()
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e6a3a9855c66> in <module>
      2 
      3 kw_list = ["covid"]
----> 4 pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='2021-02-01 2021-07-09', geo='BR', gprop='')
      5 gt_o3_ytd1 = pytrends.interest_over_time()

AttributeError: module 'pytrends' has no attribute 'build_payload'
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? it will work in paython >= 3.6.0

Comment: I'm using version 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# import the TrendReq method from the pytrends request module
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

# execute the TrendReq method by passing the host language (hl) and timezone (tz) parameters
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)

kw_list = ["covid"]
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='2021-02-01 2021-07-09', geo='BR', gprop='')
gt_o3_ytd1 = pytrends.interest_over_time()
gt_o3_ytd1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mytrend = pytrends.TrendReq()
mytrend.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='2021-02-01 2021-07-09', geo='BR', gprop='')
gt_o3_ytd1 = pytrends.interest_over_time()
```